# Communicating back and forth between Javascript and c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to write a code in c# which retrieves data from database and passes that data to javascript (within a loop one record at a time) for processing via google map api. That javascript returns a list of string which I use to carry out further processing and save to db via c#.

Until now I realized that javascript function just gets called one time even if we write it in the loop. Moreover I even don't have any idea how I will return list of string from javascript and use that inside c#.

I am badly stuck at this. Can you please suggest a good and effective method?

Thank You.

Here is the code which I have written but it didn't worked.

```
foreach (LocationDataPacket d in l)
            {

                if (d.cellPhoneGPSData == current_cell)
                {
                      lat1 = lat2;
                      long1 = long2;

                      lat2 = d.Lat;
                      long2 = d.Long;
                      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "check", "check("+d.ID+");", true);


                }
                else
                {
                    lat2 = d.Lat;
                    long2 = d.Long;
                    current_cell = d.cellPhoneGPSData;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What version of .NET? Are you up to date enough for the "one ASP.NET" changes like running WebForms (`ScriptManager` implies WebForms) in the same web app as Web API and/or SignalR. The latter two both being quite capable of shifting JSON content back and forth.

Comment: I am using 4.5 version of .net. I have seen SignalR but haven't tried it yet. Until now I was trying to invoke client function but unfortunately server side doesn't wait for client and performs all the task without calling client side code more than once

Comment: The whole model of WebForms tries to hide the underlying statelessness of HTTP. However to have processing switching from server to client and back you're going to have to undo that abstraction.

Comment: C# execution occurs on the server.  Javascript execution occurs on the client.  Are you sure the client needs to be involved in this?   It sounds like you are trying to execute a purely server-based process: 1) Get data1 from server-local db, 2) Use data1 to get data2 from Internet source, 3) Save data2 to server-local db.

Comment: @pseudocoder I think you understood the problem right. Google Map Api is javascript based therefore I am using its api to fetch some data related to my data in db. I don't think that I have any other option but to do what I am doing

Comment: Looks like the javascript client isn't the only way you can access Google API's.  See below.  Also here is the appropriate stackoverflow search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-api-dotnet-client]+map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled "accessing google maps api from .net client" and it led me to the Google APIs Client Library for .NET:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/

I'm assuming this will allow your .net program (might not even have to run on an asp.net server depending on your requirements) to become a direct google map API client so you can do all this processing locally.

Edit: Addressing your original question, in order to get data from the client back to your web server the client needs to post back the information.  This question seems to cover that pretty well: [Send javascript variables to server-side ASP .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751252/send-javascript-variables-to-server-side-asp-net) .  However I would not recommend attempting this based on what you said you wanted to accomplish.  I'd try the .NET client library for the API first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script runat="server">
foreach (LocationDataPacket d in l)
{
  if (d.cellPhoneGPSData == current_cell)
  {
    lat1 = lat2;
    long1 = long2;

    lat2 = d.Lat;
    long2 = d.Long;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "check", "check("+d.ID+");", true);
  }
  else
  {
    lat2 = d.Lat;
    long2 = d.Long;
    current_cell = d.cellPhoneGPSData;
  }
}
</script>
```

write these code into head Tag.. hope this will help u.

Comment: You mean to say I should paste all my c# code in the head of my aspx page? Are you sure that it will wait for client side code after that? Once I tried writing c# code inside javascript code and all the c# code executed at the start without waiting for javascript to finish

Comment: i provide a link in which u can use all the javascript and c# communication method implement those

Answer (score 0):

in this link you can find many method for transfer value from back c# to javascript

[C# to javascript value transfer methods](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/05/passing-net-server-side-data-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Google Maps and found a solution in using PageMethods which returned all the data at the same time in a json and then I put the markers on the map.

In my case the next call I made to collect data I cleared the previous points on the map and put up the next collection by every call (this since the user could make another selection that changed all the markers) but of course it's possible to just add new markers if it's possible in your case.